# Оптимизация запросов к БД в цикле

Tags: php, mysql, циклы, запрос

Здравствуйте! 
Есть скрипт, который должен обработать большой csv файл и проверить есть ли запись в бд. Если записи нет – добавить, есть – обновить. Всё просто.

Структура таблицы:

```
id | number | brand | price
1  |   23   |  1    | 22.3
2  |   24   |  2    | 12.3
```

Суть вопроса: сейчас скрипт в цикле делает запросы к бд на проверку существования и дальше принимает решение добавлять или обновлять. Получается много запросов и скрипт очень тормозит. On duplicate key update – работает только с полем `id` т.е. primary field. У меня есть все поля кроме `id` в цикле.

Можно ли как то увеличить производительность при такой задаче или только в цикле делать 2 запроса? Можно конечно всё сохранять в два масива и дальше делать один insert и update, но объём данных около 10М строк...

**UPD (пример запроса в цикле)**

```
    if(($part_id = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM parts WHERE `part_number` = "'.$item['part_number'].'" AND `brand_id` = "'.$item['brand_id'].'" LIMIT 1')->row_array()['id']) != FALSE)
        $this->db->update('parts', $item, array('id' => $part_id));
    else 
        $this->db->insert('parts', $item);
```

Comment: в БД есть уникальные ключи?

Comment: @xAqweRx `id` – primary field, `number` и `brand` – index. Т.е. у брендов может повторятся `number`

Comment: Скорее всего так и придется циклом. тут вопрос в том как именно вы делаете запросы. Если делать один раз перед циклом prepare а в цикле execute подготовленного запроса с параметрами - то это гораздо быстрее, чем если вы например делаете целый query внутри цикла. Далее смотреть план выполнения запроса, есть ли эффективные индексы для поиска записи

Comment: Укажите какая проверка идет в php скрипте, без этого сложно что-то посоветовать

Comment: как вариант - загрузка входящего файла во временную таблицу и сравнение таблиц единым SQL запросом, возможно быстрее будет. Особенно если файл грузить командой `load data` MySQL

Comment: @xAqweRx обновил пост. Пример проверки (CodeIgniter). Есть идея разделить на файлы и потом с помощью LOAD DATA IN FILE, но можно ли при этом обновить существующие записи?

Comment: Вот каждый второй вопрос и подставляют переменные непосредственно в текст. а потом удивляются почему тормозит. _НИКОГДА_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. Перед циклом, один раз: `$stmt=$db->prapare('SELECT id FROM parts WHERE part_number=? AND brand_id=?');`. В цикле `$stmt->bind_param('ii',$item['part_number'],$item['brand_id']); $result = $stmt->get_result(); $result->fetch....` По хорошему если нужные параметры в обычных переменных а не элементах массива, то bind_param так же делается только один раз перед циклом. внутри только get_result.

Comment: Так же и запросы insert/update один раз подготовить prepare, а внутри цикла только вызывать с новыми параметрами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент, вижу как выход:

1. В БД на поле, которое проверяеться повесить unique key -> я так понимаю, что бренд не должен повторяться. соответственно на него и вешать ключ
2. после этого выполнять  On duplicate key update или insert ignore ( в зависимости от того, какая цель )

---

**апдейт**

После обновления вопроса : unique key на поля part_number,brand, а не просто index. тогда можно спокойно делать insert ** on duplicate key update. Без дополнительных проверок.

```
ALTER TABLE `parts ` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`part_number`, `brand`);
```

Comment: У бренда может быть несколько `number`, но у каждого бренда может быть только уникальный `number`

Comment: @ka5itoshka Обновил ответ